# Why don't I receive the notification in react native iOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-notifications

So I have problem with notification in IOS, I successfully received the notification in Android but not in IOS. To configure notifications for IOS I followed the documentation of react-native firebase, here are the two links that help me

- https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/ios
- https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/ios

So, here is my configuration

`Podfile`
[image: Podfile]
`AppDelegate.h`
[image]
`AppDelegate.m``

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  ...
  return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
@end
```

here are the libraries I use

[image: Library][image]

Do you know where I made the wrong configuration to implement notifications for IOS?

Comment: Are you trying to get the notifications in a simulator? If so, you should switch to a real device as iOS doesn't allow notifications to be received on a simulator. Also, if you have used Pods then can you verify that those are correctly being installed? The screenshot you attached shows the libraries not the pods dir.

Comment: make sure your `componentWillUnmount` is not at the bottom. I made the mistake once and, lo and behold the notification for iOS works

Comment: Did you add Google-services.plist file to your project? and in firebase did you add your developer account key or apns certificates?

Comment: @SurajMalviya - no I don't test the application on the simulator and on my Pods folder there are all the folders (i.e. Firebase, FirebaseMessaging...)

Comment: @Emma - whereabouts ? my method is in this order : `constructor (){} componentDidMount(){} componentWillUnmount(){}` ...

Comment: @Kranthi - I forgot this step so I did it and it works. Thank you